# How to implement login with Room database in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I need to implement some easy login using Room Database with Kotlin. What I need is to check empty TextViews and to get whether user exist, if so I need to store to SharePreferences the value of id of user and value of zebra. I know it is very easy but I cannot find some really easy example. Can I ask for source code also?

I have a class

```
@Entity(tableName = "cis06zebras")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val login: String? = null,
    val password: String? = null,
    val surname: String? = null,
    val zebra: Int? = null
)
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
):ViewModel() {
    val users= repository.getUser().asLiveData()
```

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cis06zebras")
    fun getAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the correct the way of answering your question but i guess this repo i did can help you out with your use case: [An android app that uses Room as the main database for authentication](https://github.com/VictorKabata/ShopComp)

Comment: Thank you, I think it could help me. Can you write me, where you have SQL statement for user? And logic of empty textviews?

Comment: This is the code to the SQL queries(User DAO) https://github.com/VictorKabata/ShopComp/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/doe/compshop/data/cache/dao/UserDao.kt

and this is where the logic for the edittexts are https://github.com/VictorKabata/ShopComp/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/doe/compshop/ui/fragments/login